# access chrome or/and firefox tabs using Java

Tags: java

Is there a way to know what are the currently opened chrome or firefox tabs and their urls via Java code? I need to to see the currently opened tab and its url and if tabs are switched if possible. any ideas?

Comment: For Firefox, check out the `%AppData%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\${YOUR_HASH}.default\sessionstore.js` file to see your current 
tabs.

Comment: Are you sure you mean Java code, not JavaScript?

Comment: Google may store their's here: `%AppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Current Tabs`

Comment: Yes Stoneboy! I need to monitor many active windows and with internet browsers i need to go deeper and monitor opened tabs.